# Algorithm to sort elements of an array under uncertainty

Tags: sorting, probabilistic-algorithms

I have an array of $n$ elements. Each element is basically the mean of gamma distribution and the actual value of the element is picked from that distribution. Assume the parameters of distribution (scale and shape) are different for different elements and not known.

Now I wish to sort these means so that, after replacing each mean with a value randomly chosen from the corresponding gamma distribution, the probability that the realization is in sorted order is as large as possible.  Is there an efficient algorithm for this task?

Comment: There are many different possible interpretations here. You can ask about the order that maximizes the probability that the resulting array (after generating the actual values) is sorted; or about the order that minimizes the distance from being ordered according to some metric. Since the parameters of the distribution are not known, there is probably no algorithm with the above features for *every* choice of the unknown of parameters. But perhaps one can give an algorithm with reasonable guarantees.

Comment: The natural algorithm would be to sort according to the given means. In some case this isn't optimal.

Comment: The real problem here is that the distribution isn't really known, so it's not clear how to measure the success of the algorithm.

Comment: Specifically, gamma distributions are not determined by their mean - There's also a [shape parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution). ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @YuvalFilmus  The success will be known after the actual values are realized.

Comment: @RickyDemer That is true and I think I have mentioned that. What is your doubt?

Comment: Oh yeah, now I see you did mention that. ​ I suppose my "doubt" was that the means determined the optimal sort. ​ (That's no longer just a doubt; I confirmed with wxmaxima that when n=2 and the set of means is {12,14} and the set of shape parameters is {1,2}, the best sort is by shape parameter, regardless of which of them corresponds to which mean.) ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ So, my _question_ is ​ ​ ​ " ​ What do you mean by "the probability of this array to be sorted is high", since there's not enough information to determine "the probability of this array to be sorted"? ​ " ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Suppose we have $n$ elements. An algorithms $A$ sorts them but due to some perturbation the value of each element is changed. This perturbation is defined by gamma distribution. Now suppose we do this perturbation a $N$ times and check if the array is sorted. I want an algorithm which has higher probability that the array is sorted under these perturbations (uncertainty). What is wxMaxima? Could you please tell me what test you performed?

Comment: Well, you haven't specified enough to let us compare algorithms. ​ [wxmaxima](https://www.google.com/#q=wxmaxima) is a computer algebra system. ​ I got the expressions for the [complementary cdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Complementary_cumulative_distribution_function_.28tail_distribution.29)s of the shape=1 gamma distributions (which are just exponential distributions), and integrated to find the average, over the choice of cutoff from the shape=2 gamma distributions, of those tail probabilities. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Forget comparing algorithms. I am looking for something to start with. When the elements do not have certain values then how to sort them?

Comment: The middle of Yuval's 3 comments here describes something you can start with. ​ ​

Comment: What should be done if the distribution is not known?